# Update table using rownum

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a table that I would like to update in oracle. It's okay to assume that the rownum are in sequential order from 1 through 7

```
Table Have
1
2
3
4
4
4
4


Table Want  
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Comment: and what is your question? have you some code that you think is not correct working?

Comment: `rownum` is computed when the query results are retrieved.  There is no intrinsic connection to the actual rows.

Comment: The `rownum` is related to the `select` you are executing, not the data itself. It depends on how you order the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to have unique sequential numbers in that column.

If you don't care much about *conditions*, you could even

```
update have set col1 = rownum;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right you need something like `UPDATE` all your duplicated (in your case value = 4) rows by adding (rownum -1).

See example below.

```
create table have as 
select case when rownum <= 4 then rownum else 4 end col1 from dual connect by level <= 7;

select col1 from have order by col1;
      COL1
----------
         1 
         2 
         3 
         4 
         4 
         4 
         4 

update have
set col1 = col1 + rownum -1  where col1 = 4;

select col1 from have order by col1;

      COL1
----------
         1 
         2 
         3 
         4 
         5 
         6 
         7
```

Comment: Your solution works for the example I provided but it may not work if you have a scenario like the one below:       
   `Table Have`
    `1`
    `2`
    `3`
    `3`
    `3`
    `3`
    `4`


    `Table Want`
    `1`
    `2`
    `3`
    `4`
    `5`
    `6`
    `7`

Comment: @user2008558 feel free to adapt to `update have set col1 =   rownum  + 2  where col1 >  2` I hope you get the idea. The approach is to update only columns with wrong numbers.